# Call functions javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am starting in web desing, and I have a problem with a javascript function in external file:
My function javascript is like this:

```
function log()
{
    alert("something"); 
    $('#content').load('mod/lo.php');   
}
```

And I call this function in html like this:

```
<script>log()</script>
```

and the script only shows the alert, the function load is ignored.
But if I call the function like this:

```
<script>$(log);</script>
```

It works fine, the alert is showed and the load works.

What's the difference of these forms of calls?
I have search about this, but almost all the pages say that to call a function only put `<script>function();</script>`
Can anyone explain me the diferrence of this forms of call? there are problem when parameters are used?
Thanks and sorry for my bad English.

Comment: What is the output in console?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$` syntax is a jQuery shorthand, what it actually means is call this function when the document has loaded. It's exactly the same as writing:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert("something"); 
   $('#content').load('mod/lo.php');   
});
```

This probably indicates that the DOM item with the ID `content` doesn't yet exist when the script executes. The affect of this is the jQuery selector `$('#content')` will return 0, which prevents `load()` ever being called. Once the document has fully loaded however it will be present and your `load()` will execute.

Comment: Oohh!!
Thanks for the answer, now I understand it.

Comment: @DanteLR great, if you feel like it answered your question please feel free to accept it as the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The difference is, when you call `<script>$(log);</script>` you're actually calling `$(document).ready(log() {});` and Jquery executes its code. In the case of `<script>log()</script>` the page isn't already loaded and doesn't execute the jquery code.

[Check this page](http://www.sitepoint.com/types-document-ready/)